# Is it safe to download and test EICAR test file

Tags: ubuntu

I need a sample malicious file that I can work with but does not harm my system. When I checked through the internet I found there is a file called EICAR test file. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Can I safely use this?

These are the references I checked

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file

https://www.eicar.org/download-anti-malware-testfile/

Comment: Short answer: as the links you show tell you, it is designed to be safe. I'm not sure what else we can add to that.

Comment: in the second link it says YOU DOWNLOAD THESE FILES AT YOUR OWN RISK. There was no resource that says they have tested in ubuntu and found no issue, that's why i asked this question to be sure if its safe for ubuntu users.

Comment: And it explains the risk... It has nothing to do with the OS, but with the AV you use.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with django or file uploads. You want this file to test those things, but your question has nothing to do with that. So, please don't add irrelevant tags. You want to know if EICAR test file is safe to process on Ubuntu. The rest of the context is irrelevant.

Comment: @AvinMathew Your own risk is not if the file is harmful, but if your programs react in a harmful way. Think of, for example, a virus scanner that moves your VM image into quarantine because it detects the EICAR string inside. This test would prove that your virus scanner can detect VM images with viruses inside, but at the same time it may quarantine or delete a VM image that contained other important files.